# Ktor Test Engine - Logging

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I'm running unit tests with ktor testing engine and everything is perfect locally. However, once I deploy on Travis, tests are failing and it seems the test engine is not running properly:

- https://travis-ci.org/vpasquier/sprint-review/builds/406708799 (see down the logs).
- ([here is my simple test](https://github.com/vpasquier/sprint-review/blob/master/sprint-review-server/src/test/kotlin/com/sprintreview/test/SmokeTestServer.kt#L18-L27))

There is not enough info in trace mode unfortunately. (`<logger name="io.ktor.server.testing" level="TRACE"/>`)

Do you know how we can activate more logs for investigating? Or if you have any other idea to fix it?

If you tell me that Travis is not out dated, not recommended, I can switch too.

Thank you

Comment: Start by installing CallLogging so you can see what happens: `install(CallLogging) { level = Level.INFO }`

Comment: By the way, I just cloned you repo and I get the same error locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your travis build is missing the static files. 
Your `deployWeb` task does not seem to be executed as you only run `./gradlew test --info || travis_terminate 1` .

Therefore, the resource doesn't exist and will result in an unhandled route.

It works when I add `static/index.html` to the resources.

Comment: Thank you Andreas, actually i'm deploying the resources with the `gradle stage` but I did that after the testing... My bad. Thank you as well for the CallLogging!